# How to install brew on Unix 13.10

Tags: homebrew

I need to install fleetctl and I found a tutorial that says to use

```
    brew install fleetctl
```

The thing is, I don't have brew installed, and when I follow this tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-use-linuxbrew-on-a-linux-vps) and type

```
    which brew
```

afterwards, nothing happens. So, how do I get brew working? I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brew](http://brew.sh/), or Homebrew, is a package manager for OS X. Therefore, it will not work on Ubuntu, which is a Debian flavored Linux.

Package managers means that someone has precompiled source code. It doesn't look like Ubuntu's package manager, apt-get, has a precompiled version.

However, the creators of fleetctl have a compiled version here:

https://github.com/coreos/fleet > Releases > [fleet-v0.8.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz](https://github.com/coreos/fleet/releases/download/v0.8.3/fleet-v0.8.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz)

So on your box:

1. Download it:

   ```
   $ wget https://github.com/coreos/fleet/releases/download/v0.8.3/fleet-v0.8.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz
   ```
2. Untar it:

   ```
   $ tar -xvf fleet-v0.8.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz
   ```
3. It's not installed yet, as you can see from `which` but it'll run:

   ```
   $ which fleetctl
   /usr/bin/which: no fleetctl in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/ec2-user/bin)

   $ ./fleet-v0.8.3-linux-amd64/fleetctl
   ```
4. (Optional but recommended) Install it by moving to /usr/local/bin

   ```
   $ sudo cp fleet-v0.8.3-linux-amd64/fleetctl /usr/local/bin
   ```
5. You can prove that it's installed and run it from any directory:

   ```
   $ which fleetctl
   /usr/local/bin/fleetctl
   $ fleetctl
   ```

Comment: You can also build it from source using their instructions here: https://github.com/coreos/fleet#building